# Rotating elements in a link

Tags: html, css

```css
    a{
                            border: 1px solid black;
                            transform: rotate(65deg);
                        }
```

```html
    <div class="caption__link">
        <a href="#">hello</a>
    </div>
```

I am trying to make what is in the link rotate but its not working, I used a font-awesome icon originally but turns out it doesn't work with texts too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Elements with a `display` property of `inline` cannot be transformed like this.

As it's a text link (which is `inline` by default) you can add `display: inline-block;` to enable this.

```css
a {
  border: 1px solid black;
  transform: rotate(65deg);
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="caption__link">
  <a href="#">hello</a>
</div>
```